# items inside UIStackView overflowing

Tags: swift, uistackview

I've created a `UIStackView` programmatically and inside placed `UITextView`s.
when the number of the `UITextView`s is more than 5 the boxes start overflowing off the screen. Here's a screenshot of the situation:

[image]

And here's the code :

```
let stackview = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: letterBoxes)
stackview.axis = .horizontal
stackview.spacing = 10
stackview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.view.addSubview(stackview)
stackview.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
stackview.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
```

what am I missing? 
thank you

Comment: What should the expected outcome be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also add `.leading` and `.trailing` constraints like this

```
view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackview, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))            
view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackview, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
```

so the complete code looks like:

```
let stackview = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: letterBoxes)
stackview.axis = .horizontal
stackview.spacing = 10
stackview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.view.addSubview(stackview)
stackview.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
stackview.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackview, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackview, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
```

Comment: thanks! what would be the best way to get each character the user typed and validate it against the correct answer [ i also have a hint button which auto-complete 1 character every time user request a hint so I'm not sure what would be the best approach for this]

Comment: @NetaYamin please ask it as a new question and accept this one if it helped. :) .. Hint: You can use `textFieldDidChange` and inside this compare your `textField.text` with thd correct answer.